# mut String redeclaration inside loop

Tags: string, loops, rust, mutability

I'm reading the Rust book and the guessing game tutorial has the following code:

```
use rand::Rng;
use std::cmp::Ordering;
use std::io;
use std::io::Write;

fn main() {
    let secret_number = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(1, 101);
    let mut input = String::new();

    loop {
        print!("Guess the number I'm thinking of: ");
        io::stdout().flush().unwrap();
        io::stdin().read_line(&mut input).expect("Failed to read line");

        let guess: u32 = match input.trim().parse() {
            Ok(num) => num,
            Err(_) => continue
        };

        println!("\nYou guessed: {}", guess);

        match guess.cmp(&secret_number) {
            Ordering::Less => println!("Too small!"),
            Ordering::Greater => println!("Too big!"),
            Ordering::Equal => {
                println!("You win!");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code fails after the first user input. If I move the `let mut input = String::new();` declaration inside the loop then everything is ok... But I'm wondering why I have to do that since the address of `input` is passed into `read_line()`?

And one more thing why do I have to use `std::io::Write` in order to use `io::stdout().flush().unwrap();` since I'm already using `use std::io;`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```rust
io::stdin().read_line(&mut input);
```

This method doesn't overwrite the [`String`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html) but it appends to the `String`. This is why only the first iteration of the loop works but it immediately breaks on the second iteration. If you want to re-use the `String` buffer between iterations you need to truncate it before passing it back into [`read_line`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.Stdin.html#method.read_line). Fixed working example:

```rust
use rand::Rng;
use std::cmp::Ordering;
use std::io;
use std::io::Write;

fn main() {
    let secret_number = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(1, 101);
    let mut input = String::new();

    loop {
        print!("Guess the number I'm thinking of:");
        io::stdout().flush().unwrap();
        
        input.clear(); // truncate String buffer here!

        io::stdin()
            .read_line(&mut input)
            .expect("Failed to read line");

        let guess: u32 = match input.trim().parse() {
            Ok(num) => num,
            Err(_) => continue,
        };

        println!("\nYou guessed: {}", guess);

        match guess.cmp(&secret_number) {
            Ordering::Less => println!("Too small!"),
            Ordering::Greater => println!("Too big!"),
            Ordering::Equal => {
                println!("You win!");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> And one more thing why do I have to use `std::io::Write` in order to use `io::stdout().flush().unwrap();` since I'm already using use `std::io;`?

In order to call trait methods you need to bring the trait into scope. [`flush`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Write.html#tymethod.flush) is defined by the [`Write`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Write.html) trait.